# What is the purpose of CRX file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Chrome Store does not accept `CRX` file but simple `ZIP` file.

So I am confused why the `CRX` files exist? Also extracting the `ZIP` file and loading it unpacked option is still an option.

As far as I know Chrome does not allow extension installation other than Chrome Store.

So what is the purpose of the `CRX` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to privately host an extension. To do this you need to host the CRX file. There's some information about this in the [Google docs for hosting extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting).

If you have a managed Chromebook for example, then you can push out a privately hosted Chrome extension to users. There's an example of this in the [Google help docs for managing apps/extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6177431?hl=en) under the 'Select apps and extensions for your users' section.

By privately hosting the extension it doesn't need to be in the Chrome store.

Answer (score 4):

To add to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36208677): CRX has some extra metadata (it's signed with the extension's private key) compared to a ZIP. A CRX file can still be opened with a ZIP archiver though.

Since CWS does the signing itself (having the private key), it does not require a CRX.